# Is "et al." one or two words?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, writing, spelling, style

I use [et al.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/et%20al.) to refer to a paper with more than two authors. However, the word `et` got separated by a line (due to line end) and the word `al.` cam in the beginning of a new line.

> ... Authorname [end of line]
>
> et al. [4] find ...

They are separated by a space, so my editor did not add `-` and consideres them as two words.

Is this ok? Or do they have to come as one word?

Comment: Is *ice cream* or *mother-in-law* a word? It depends on how you interpret such entries in the dictionary. They are *treated* as single syntactic units. As such, they could be *considered* a word (or *word unit*). The Latin *et al.* means *and others*, which is two words. However, in our usage of it, we treat it in the same way that we treat *ice cream*. By the way, there are open, hyphenated, and closed words (or phrases or expressions). Just because they are open doesn't necessarily mean that they are considered to be *two* (or more) words.

Comment: I would maybe add a non-breaking space between 'et' and 'al.' to make sure they always end up together, avoiding this conundrum :)

Answer (score -1):

"et al." is a phrase consisting of two words. It is short for *er alia* (or *alii* or *aliae* depending on gender) which is Latin for "and others", and so should be in italics. It could be formatted with a non-breaking space, to avoid this problem. Different style guides have different rules for when and if it should be used. See [this MW dictionary entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/et%20al.) for more info.

Comment: I don't agree it *should* be italicized. According to the [official APA blog](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/05/its-all-latin-to-me.html), it doesn't have to be italicized.

Comment: @David Siegel Thanks. But I do not see an answer for my question. Is breaking them ok or not?

Comment: @user178049 Any given style guide will have its own rules, but i think the default is still to use italics unless the  particular style guide in use says otherwise.

Comment: @none You asked, is it one word or two. I answered two,  It is always OK to break a line at any word break, although one tries to avoid a single word alone on a line, perhaps by forcing a break earlier. It is certainly better to keep "et al" together if possible but there is no rule that requires doing so, and that is the kind of thing that an editor gets to decide, in light of the house style, if any.